# app closes without going to the second screen

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

This is the main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var userInput:EditText = findViewById(R.id.usr_input) as EditText
        var button:Button = findViewById(R.id.ent_btn) as Button

        button.setOnClickListener {
            var name = userInput.text

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, screenTwo::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", name)

            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is second screen

```
class screenTwo : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_two)


        var userName:TextView = findViewById(R.id.user_name) as TextView
        var editText:EditText = findViewById(R.id.usr_text) as EditText
        var outText:TextView = findViewById(R.id.output) as TextView
        var showButton:Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_show) as Button
        var back:Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_back) as Button

        var name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        userName.text = name

        showButton.setOnClickListener {
            var text:String = editText.text.toString()
            outText.text = text
        }

        back.setOnClickListener {
            var goback = Intent(this@screenTwo, MainActivity::class.java)

            startActivity(goback)
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the button(variable_name) in the main activity, the app closes. Is it the intent or something is wrong in the second screen???

Comment: Post  the error log.

Comment: This is most likely due to a crash. Meaning you got a stacktrace in the logcat. Please investigate relevant traces and logs.

Comment: does it crash? Does it say that your app has stopped?

Comment: I expect an error durint layout inflation... Please post logcat output!

Comment: in kotlin why use `findViewById` just use the id of  any view like `ent_btn.setOnClickListener { }`

Comment: `screenTwo` is probably not registered in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

**intent** is not defind in **SecondActivity**

In **SecondActivity** : get intent by `getIntent()`

> class screenTwo : AppCompatActivity() {
>
> var name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name")

Comment: Yes it is defined: `var name = intent.getStringExtra("name")`. With Kotlin `intent` is what for Java is `getIntent()` (Property Access Syntax).

Comment: Thanks @forpas for your help

Answer (score 0):

Most common error in this configuration is that you forgot to declare your *screenTwo* in your AndroidManifest.xml, inside the "application" node (your *MainActivity* should already be defined there) :

```
 <activity 
     android:name=".screenTwo"
     android:theme="yourTheme"/>
```

If this is not it, an error log might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , it was a minor error from my side..
I didn't convert the variable 'name' to 'String'

```
var name = userInput.text.toString()    //correction
```

It's working now,
Thanks anyway...